# How to write code for if there are two overlapping if conditions in code

Tags: coding-style

There are two functions isBusy and isSad. I want to implement the following logic in most readable and production ready way. But I am not sure if it is the ideal way to write code since the function isSad is called twice.

```
if isBusy
{
    person.busy=true
    if isSad
    {
        person.sad=true
    }
    return person
}

if isSad
{
    person.sad=true
    return person
}
// some code

return person
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you after something like this?

```
person.busy = isBusy

person.sad = isSad

if person.busy or person.sad
{
    return person
}

// run logic 

return person
```

Comment: No. If isBusy or isSad is true, then the person should be returned immediately without having any further logic

Comment: I’ve amended my answer to take that into account. Just make that your first check in the subsequent logic

Comment: But isBusy and isSad should not be set true by default. My code is correct logic wise. I just want to know that what is the best way of writing this

Comment: If you don’t want to move your code around you could set isSad to populate a variable and use that to do your checks. That way the function isSad will only get called once

Comment: But I will still have to call it again in the case where isBusy is false

Comment: No. Once you place the value inside a variable you can check the variable as many times as you like without re-calling the function

Comment: What would be the best scenario for coding when isBusy and isSad are variables. I will have to check the value twice

Comment: Checking a boolean variable is insignificant in terms of processing. The properties sad and busy on the person object are actually variables. So you could just set them as per my original answer. Then check against those like I did when checking if you need to return the person right away.